# Git: How to give warning before adding the untracked file with specific extension

Tags: git

When we add the untracked file with a specific extension (say *.txt) then it should give a pop-up with questions like "Have you done sanity check before?" and upon the answer, it will add that file.

I know there is .gitignore but it will ignore the file completely.

Comment: You could probably do this in a pre-commit hook. I don't know of a git-add hook, but a pre-commit hook could look for added files with the given extension in the commit and perform the actions you want.

Comment: Of course, pre-commit hooks have the weakness that each developer must enable them individually in each sandbox, so they're not very effective for team enforcement of rules and recommendations.